# Setting multiple model attributes at once via loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im using virtual attributes to concat and form a address before i save the user. So when they click edit user i would like to populate the fields in the form again. Every time i try to assign them they come back nil?

This is what i call from devise registrations controller before_action edit:

```
def test
 resource.populate_address_attributes
end
```

and here is the method im trying to work with:

```
def populate_address_attributes
  if address == nil || address == ""
    return false
  else
    attributes = address.split(",")
    [self.number, self.street_name, self.area, self.postcode, self.state].each { |x| x = attributes.delete_at[0]}
  end
end
```

all i'm getting is this:

```
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

maybe i'm trying to make it to complicated?

Comment: Ill add the attributes array is populated correctly with the address split up

Comment: Why do you store the address as a single comma separated string?

Comment: because geocoder allows it with comma's and i cant split with " " incase of multiple words in the street name or city

Comment: Storing the address as a single concatenated comma seperated string seems like a really bad idea since addresses may actually contains commas (`596 Ocean Blvd, APT 162`) for example. The idea of being able to parse addresses with simple methods is utterly flawed. You're basically taking good seperated data and turing it into junk.

Comment: @max ok seems fair, how would you suggest i go about it?

Comment: Use separate columns for each segment of the address of course and combine them for geocoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing `[self.number, self.street_name]` etc you are passing the value of those attributes (which are nil and hence immutable).

Try this

```
def populate_address_attributes
  if address == nil || address == ""
    return false
  else
    attributes = address.split(",")
    [:number, :street_name, :area, :postcode, :state].each_with_index do |field, index|
      self.public_send("#{field}=", attributes[index])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can't write unknown attribute `field`

Comment: sorry, there was a bug, fixed. Try again

Comment: Should had been `self[field]` instead of `self[:field]`

Comment: now its throwing "*** ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError Exception: can't write unknown attribute `number`"   In byebug i can set self.number to 3 and then self[field] is showing nil and it should be 3. Im a bit confused!

Comment: Are `number`, `street_name`, ... etc virtual attributes or actual fields on the model?

Comment: If you are trying to just set virtual attributes, try `self.public_send("#{field}=", attributes[index])` instead of  `self[field] = attributes[index]`

Comment: @johnseymour Any luck?

Comment: sorry asleep let try shortly and ill get back to you. Yes they are virtual attributes

Comment: yes great this has worked, can you write an answer ill mark it complete. thanks

Comment: @johnseymour I have updated the answer but do you understand why my solutions works and yours don't?

Comment: So i think i understand it, basically i was storing the values of the variables in the array, not setter methods. so by calling public send(number, 4) on the user object its effectively calling the setter method in this case?